# Is possible to add to already loaded schema some new static functions from some file?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Is possible to add to already loaded schema some new static functions from some file ?
I tried like to extends schema in mongoose

```
_ = require('lodash');
var schema = new mongoose.Schema(model.schema, model.options);
_.extend(schema, require('../extension/person_statics'));
```

but I get error

```
      throw new MongooseError.OverwriteModelError(name);
            ^
OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Person` model once compiled.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is not possible to modify or extend a schema that was compiled.

The best practices to create a mongoose schema, is first of all initialize all your models with its specific schemas, and then compile all together.

This workflow may be difficult some times, I recommend you that use a framework for your models.

Check this framework for express and mongoose:

https://github.com/codexar/rode

The models are compiled on demand to prevent your problem.

I hope I have helped!